# Compilation error with sexplib

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I need to use Sexplib in my program. I tried

```
ocamlc sexplib.cma prog.ml
Error: Unbound module Sexplib
```

and I got the error. But I can use Sexplib in top level if I load ppx_sexp_conv package first:

```
#require "ppx_sexp_conv";;
open Sexplib;;
```

So I also tried this:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_sexp_conv sexplib.cma prog.ml
Error: Error while linking /Users/neko/.opam/system/lib/sexplib/sexplib.cma(Sexplib):
The external function `caml_ba_get_1' is not available
```

I have no idea what this means and what I need to do now... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`caml_ba_get_1` is a function of the Bigarray module. You might try linking in the bigarray package (or `bigarray.cma`). On my system the function is defined in `libbigarray.a`.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is missing C externals used by your package. You should be able to fix this by passing `-linkpkg` to `ocamlfind` so that it passes the relevant arguments to the linker:

```
ocamlc -package ppx_sexp_conv -linkpkg prog.ml
```